# C# Two decimal places

Tags: c#, .net

How do I insert decimal point into string?

```
int attrval = Convert.ToInt32("000504");
decimal val1 = (attrval / 100);  
string val2 = String.Format("{0:.00}", attrval / 100);
```

`val1 = 5`    need `5.04`

`val2 = 5.00` need `5.04`

Comment: `decimal val1 = (attrval / 100.0m);`

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with *integer division* in the line

```
 decimal val1 = (attrval / 100);
```

Since *both* `attrval` and `100` are of type `int` the result is `int` as well: `5`. This line should be

```
 decimal val1 = (attrval / 100m);
```

please, note `m` suffix: here we divide `int` by `decimal` (`100m`) and have a desired `decimal` result. Same for `val2`:

```
 string val2 = String.Format("{0:.00}", attrval / 100m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Division of two integer numbers **return integer value as a result**. This division rounds resultant value towards zero, that is why you are getting `val2 = 5` instead of `5.04`.

If you want result to be in `decimal` type, convert at-least one value either numerator or denominator to the `decimal`.

```
decimal val1 = (attrval / (decimal)100);  //5.04
```

or

```
decimal val1 = (attrval / 100m);    //5.04
```

Now convert it into string,

```
string val2 = String.Format("{0:.00}", var1); //"5.04"
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dpi9MG)